# How to separate debug and release builds with respect to their api destinations in React Native

Tags: react-native, django-rest-framework

Originally I ran a local server on my PC in order to make my django REST api available for my React Native app to reach out to through my computer's ip. So I had a base url hardcoded into my js network utilities as `http://10.0.0.xxx:8000/api/` which I used as the basis for all my network calls. Recently I deployed my backend to Heroku so that I could demonstrate my app when away from my computer. So for now I just made a second hardcoded base url of `https://my-cool-app.heroku.com/api/` which I manually flip back and forth between in my js code depending on if I want to use my local server (for debugging while devving) or the remote server for demonstration (and by "manually flip back and forth", I mean I literally change my code to point to one or the other).

I understand this is a terrible way to go about things and that I'm missing some major pieces to the puzzle that probably apply not just to RN projects but to most full stack projects where the frontend and backend are not hosted on the same server. I know I can look for the `__DEV__` flag to see if I'm working in a debug or release version, but then would I have to keep two versions of the app on my phone somehow? Also, does it even make sense to keep my base urls hanging around on the front end, or should they be dispensed from the backend in some way instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally use :

https://github.com/zetachang/react-native-dotenv

for my environment variables like my backend api and other configs based on the env.

Since it's similar to many backend libs like django or laravel, i absolutely love this library for managing environment variables :)

Comment: This seems like a good library for managing env variables, but I'm still wondering if people usually have two versions of the app (debug and release) installed on their phone, or if this isn't the correct way to approach testing.

Comment: I dont have two versions. I make a release build once in a few to test performances and see if everything is fine at the end of each of my sprints.

Comment: Does that mean you have to uninstall your debug version before installing the release one every time? I only recently learned how to create a signed/aligned apk for Android in order to run the app on my phone without being connected to the dev server on my PC, and the first time i installed it it told me the app was already installed, so I had to uninstall the debug one first before it would let me install the release one. Be nice if I could figure out how to make them "different apps" so that they could both be installed simultaneously. But maybe that warrants a separate SO question.

Comment: Indeed you need to uninstall the debug app. But if you do it often, i would change the package name for your android app when doing debugging that way both can be installed simultaneously.